# C# sort Listbox, add to a sorted list

Tags: c#, sorting, listbox, sortedlist

I want to sort the elements in C# listbox by some field in the object element.

Is there a method in C# that perform this task? Maybe a function that receives a comparison function as a parameter or something like that?

another thing, when the listbox is sorted I want to add an element to a sorted list. is there such a method?

thanks

Comment: A Winforms or WPF listbox? Also, what do you mean by "the object element"?

Comment: each element in the listbox is an object with a field by which I want to sort.

Comment: there's no such thing as a "C# ListBox". C# is a language, not an UI framework... If you don't tell us which UI framework you're using (Windows Forms, WPF, Silverlight, ASP.NET...), we can't really help you...

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using classical winforms binding to a `System.Collections.SortedList.List<TKey,TValue>` . All of the sorting will be done for you by the list, and most of the data transactions to and from the ListBox control will be done for you by the binding framework.

Comment: "and most of the data transactions to and from the ListBox control will be done for you by the binding framework" - which binding framework?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.databindings.aspx etc.